# What is the optimal way to configure IP addressing for the core Tridion 2013 SP1 infrastructure in EC2?

Tags: 2013-sp1, infrastructure

I am using DHCP to assign primary IP addresses in a subnet within Amazon Web Services EC2

To avoid issues where the boxes are rebooted and the DHCP address changes, I have assigned a secondary IP to the NIC in the same subnet which is static and I reference those in the configuration files.

Although this has worked for months, this seems a little dirty - is there an SDL or community recommended way to configure the relevant Tridion components?

Answer (score 1):

In my AWS options I have access to 4 "Elastic IPs" that I can assign to any of my instances. This - I guess - is an option we have in the contract with AWS, not sure how/why I have this :)

These are static, public IPs that I can use and re-allocate at any time to point to any of my machines, and didn't have trouble with this so far.

Comment: this is fine for public instances, but not so good for securing (for example) a database or app server.  You're really supposed to use a VPC/NAT for "internal" boxes with non-addressable subnets.  It feels like a scriptable templated solution involving Chef and some sort of DNS would be a way forward but as usual with AWS there's 100 ways to skin the proverbial cat.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't think of the "non-public" parts of it. You may want to try your luck on a more generic infra forum...

Comment: @mpaton I think Nuno makes a valid point here, even though your question is in essense related to Tridion and tyou might get a valid answer from the community here, it can also be seen as a generic AWS issue: "how do I get my database and application server to keep communicating after reboots when they have a DHCP assigned IP". Posting it in http://serverfault.com/ will probabaly give you a much better response.